# Appium ToggleWiFi in Simulator Stops the Test

Tags: automated-tests, appium, offline, appium-android, appium-desktop

I am trying to run few offline tests in Android based on ToggleWiFi, but but after turning of the WiFi appium is losing server connection. Is there any way to run tests offline in Appium Simulator by toggling Wifi.

[Appium ServerLog](https://gist.github.com/ikhaled28/808e7935f814990ba1bef7d63f663e7e)

Comment: please share your code

Comment: I was trying to implement just toggleWifi method from Appium, there is nothing else to share. After the toggleWifi method is called, testng reports 0 tests and 0 skipped. http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/device/network/toggle-wifi/

Answer (score 0):

Try this helper method way of turning the wifi off. And keep the test execution going as it is.  ( Android Only )

```
static AppiumDriver driver;    

public static void wifiOff() throws InterruptedException {
NetworkConnection mobileDriver = (NetworkConnection) driver;
if (mobileDriver.getNetworkConnection() != 
ConnectionType.AIRPLANE_MODE) {
   // enabling Airplane mode

  mobileDriver.setNetworkConnection(ConnectionType.AIRPLANE_MODE);
 }
}
```

Comment: Hi, from the Appium docs I can see that its not supported by all devices. As I want use  ToggleWiFi  method from Appium it would be nice if you can say why toggleWifi is killing everything. http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/other/network-connection/

Comment: Hi, Are you testing on a connected device or on an Emulator.

Comment: I am planning for both now in Simulator, but my ultimate goal is to run on Real Devices.